# JSONAta get the name of the key containing value

Tags: json, jsonpath, jsonparser, jsonata

I am using JSONAta library to pass through a complex object. I need to get the name of the keys if it matches a certain condition.

```
{
"properties": {
                "WTID": {
                    "pattern": "reference-data",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "VCRSID": {
                    "pattern": "reference-data",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "VMSID": {
                    "pattern": "reference-data",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "DroneID": {
                    "pattern": "unique-data",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
}
```

I want all the name of the keys whose pattern is equal to reference-data i.e. WTID, VCRSID, VMSID. How is it possible to do using JSONAta Query.

So far I have tried using below query:

```
**[$contains(pattern, 'reference-data')]
```

but this returns only the values and I am unable to refer to any of the keys.

Answer (score 2):

If you're expecting `["WTID", "VCRSID","VMSID"]` as a result, then this is the solution:

```
$keys(properties) ~> $filter(function ($key) {
  $lookup(properties, $key).pattern = "reference-data"
})
```

1. Get all the keys of the `properties` object as an array.
2. Go through each key, lookup for the value at `$key` inside `properties` object.
3. Return the key only if `pattern` property from the object from the previous step equals to `"reference-data"`

You can also play with the [interactive version of this solution here](https://www.stedi.com/jsonata/playground?state=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%2BPiAkZmlsdGVyKGZ1bmN0aW9uICgka2V5KSB7XG4gICRsb29rdXAocHJvcGVydGllcywgJGtleSkucGF0dGVybiA9IFwicmVmZXJlbmNlLWRhdGFcIlxufSkifQ%3D%3D).